# Can i click on a button by de href or the class?

Tags: html, vba, class, internet-explorer, href

I'm current trying to click on a button but it has no id or class name, just class and href.

The html code is:

```
<a href="#" class="bt-acessar-login radius" onclick="validarFornecedor()" ;="">
  <i></i>
  <span>Acessar sistema</span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </a>
```

And the vba code I tried is:

```
Set btnObject = .document.getElementByClass("bt-acessar-login radius")
btnObject.FireEvent ("onclick")
```

Comment: `getElementByClass` is not a thing - did you mean `getElementsByClassName` ?  Also - the actual method returns a collection, not a single element, so you'd need something like `btnObject(0).FireEvent ("onclick")`

Comment: Actually  i just give a shot for the `getElementByClass`, and now i change the code to: `Set elems = ` `.document.getElementsByClassName("bt-acessar-login radius")`
           ` For Each e In elems`
           `If (e.getAttribute("onclick") = "validarFornecedor()") Then`
                `e.SetFocus`
                `e.Click`
                `Exit For`
            `End If`
            `Next e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i search some more and find this code who works for me !

```
Set elems = .document.getElementsByClassName("bt-acessar-login radius")
        For Each e In elems
        If (e.getAttribute("onclick") = "validarFornecedor()") Then
            e.Focus
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If
        Next e
```